# Characterizing $\mathbf{R}$ as an ordered group

Tags: gr.group-theory, real-analysis, order-theory, linear-orders, ordered-groups

A standard characterization of $\mathbf{R}$ uses the order and the field structure: any linearly ordered field that is archimedean and complete is isomorphic to $(\mathbf{R}, +, \times, <)$ as an ordered field.

Is there a similar characterization of $\mathbf{R}$ as an ordered group?

Is any linearly ordered group that is archimedean and complete isomorphic to $(\mathbf{R}, +, <)$ as an ordered group or is some other assumption needed? Any reference is welcome.

Comment: What definition of 'archimedean' do you use?

Comment: The only definition of Archimedean I can imagine here is: for all $x,y>0$ there exists $n\ge 1$ such that $nx\ge y$ where $nx=x+\dots+x$ ($n$ times).

Comment: Yes, that's the standard one for linearly ordered groups.

Comment: The ordered set $(\mathbf{R},\le)$ can be characterized as the Dedekind completion of any countable dense total order. I expect that the ordered group $(\mathbf{R},+,\le)$ is (up to isomorphism of ordered groups) the only ordered abelian group whose underlying ordered set is isomorphic to $(\mathbf{R},\le)$.

Comment: I think that the archimedean property follows from the completeness axiom.

Comment: Yes, the reals are the only nondiscrete completely ordered group. I'm pretty sure something like that has been asked on MO before.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: I think I have also seen this result somewhere, but I can't remember the reference right now, and I can't find it in Fuchs' book (see my answer below), either. Do you have a reference?

Comment: You can find it in the book  by V. A. Zorich *Mathematical Analysis I*, Sec. 2.2.3.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: Thanks for the reference! I think we missunderstood each other: Zorich's book derives the Archimedean property from the completeness for linearly ordered fields. But I think the same should be true for linearly ordered groups, too. I've just found a proof for this for commutative groups, but I'm not quite sure if it's true for non-commutative groups, too.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek "the reals are the only nondiscrete completely ordered group" - What do you mean by nondiscrete? You must not mean "discrete" w.r.t. the order topology because otherwise we have $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @coudy it was pretty clear that I meant without the upper and lower bound (just filling the holes). I heard plenty of times that $\mathbf{R}$ can be defined as the Dedekind completion of $\mathbf{Q}$, so I think this wording is valid too.

Comment: @Qfwfq I do mean discrete wrt order topology. The order of $\mathbb Q$ is not complete. As explained in the answer below, the only completely ordered abelian groups are $0$, $\mathbb Z$, and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek: oh I see, I thought "completely ordered" was just a synonym with "totally ordered". Clearly, I don't know much about ordered structures and the terminology in the field.

Comment: @YCor: It seems to me that coudy's remark on "without smallest and largest element" did not refer to the process of completion, but to the countable densely and totally ordered set in your comment. The assertion "the completion of any countable dense totally ordered set $S$ is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{R}$" is indeed not correct as coudy's example $S = [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ shows. The correct assertion is "If $S$ is a countable dense totally ordered set *and* $S$ does neither have a minimum nor a maximum, then the completion of $S$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck OK thanks. Anyway I was more interested by the second part of my comment, which you confirmed in your answer (Corollary 7).

Comment: @JochenGlueck Yes, you are correct. Zorich regards $\mathbb{R}$ as an ordered field.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The linearly ordered group $(\mathbb{Z},+,\le)$ is a counterexample, but that is probably not what the OP had in mind. To give a detailed description of the situation, let us use the following notation:

- By a *linearly bi-ordered group* we mean a tuple $(G,\cdot,\le)$ where $(G,\cdot)$ is a group and $\le$ is a linear order on $G$ such that $ac \le bc$ and $ca \le cb$ whenever $a,b,c \in G$ such that $a \le b$. We use the notion *linearly ordered group* as shorthand or *linearly bi-ordered group*.
- An *isomorphism* between two linearly ordered groups $(G,\cdot,\le)$ and $(H,\cdot,\le)$ is a group isomorphism $\varphi: (G,\cdot) \to (H,\cdot)$ such that both $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ are increasing.
- A linearly ordered group $(G,\cdot,\le)$ (whose neutral element we denote by $e$) is called *Archimedean* if, for all $a,b > e$ there exists an integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^n \ge b$.
- We call a linear order an a set $S$ *complete* if every non-empty subset of $S$ that is bounded above has a supremum in $S$ (equivalently, every non-empty subset of $S$ that is bounded below has an infimum in $S$). Note that this property is sometimes called *conditionally complete* (instead of *complete*) in the literature.

**Theorem 1.** Let $(G,\cdot,\le)$ be an Archimedean linearly ordered group. Then $(G,\cdot)$ is isomorphic to an ordered subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+,\le)$ (i.e. a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ which carries the order inherited from $\mathbb{R}$). In particular, $(G,\cdot)$ is commutative.

This result can, for instance, be found in [Theorem 1 in Section IV.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=A_QxAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA45) of

*Fuchs, L.*, Partially ordered algebraic systems, Oxford-London-New York-Paris: Pergamon Press. IX, 229 p. (1963). [ZBL0137.02001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0137.02001).
There, the theorem is attributed to Hölder.

As kindly pointed out by user Alec Rhea in the comments, there is a [related result by Hahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_embedding_theorem) which gives a description of all *commutative* linearly ordered groups.

Next we note that linearly ordered groups whose order is complete are automatically Archimedean:

**Theorem 2.** Let $(G,\cdot,\le)$ be a linearly ordered group and assume that the order $\le$ on $G$ is complete. Then $(G,\cdot,\le)$ is Archimedean.

*Proof.* Let $e$ denote the neutral element of $(G,\cdot)$, let $a,b > e$ and assume for a contradiction that $a^n < b$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then the set $S := \{a^n: \, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ has a supremum $s$ in $G$. We have $a^{-1}s < s$, so $a^{-1}s < a^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Consequently, $s < a^{n+1} \le s$, which is a contradiction.

In an earlier version of this post, a more complicated proof of Theorem 2 was given. The above version of the proof was kindly pointed out by user Emil Jeřábek in the comments.

**Remark 3.** Note that the existence of inverse elements is esssential not only for the proof, but also for the validity of Theorem 2. Indeed, the set $[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)$, endowed with componentwise addition and the lexicographical order, is an example of a linearly ordered semigroup (whose composition operation is strictly monotone in both components) which is order complete but not Archimedean.

By combining Theorems 1 and 2 we arrive at the following corollary which, I think, answers the question of the OP:

**Corollary 4.** Let $(G,\cdot,\le)$ be a linearly ordered group. If the order $\le$ on $G$ is complete, then $(G,\cdot,\le)$ is isomorphic to one of the three linearly ordered groups $(\{0\},+,\le)$, $(\mathbb{Z},+,\le)$ and $(\mathbb{R},+,\le)$.

*Proof.* According to Theorem 2 $(G,\cdot,\le)$ is Archimedean, so it is isomorphic to an ordered subgroup $(H,+,\le)$ of $(\mathbb{R},+,\le)$ due to Theorem 1. If $H$ has only one element, then obviously $H = \{0\}$, so assume that $H$ has at least two elements. Now we distinguish two cases:

*First case: $h_0 := \inf \{h \in H: \, h > 0\} > 0$.* Then it is easy to see that $H = h_0 \mathbb{Z}$, so $(H,+,\le)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+,\le)$.

*Second case: $\inf \{h \in H: \, h > 0\} = 0$.* Then one readily checks that the set $H$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and the completeness of the order on $H$
implies that $H = \mathbb{R}$. This proves the corollary.

**-- Note on edits made 2018-06-10. --** I rewrote the answer and consolidated the various edits from the previous versions in order to make this post better readable for future visitors. I also incorporated various suggestions by users  Alec Rhea, Emil Jeřábek and YCor, so let me thank them for their comments!

Comment: Very nice answer, it may be worth mentioning that the embedding theorem attributed to Holder at the beginning is a special case of the Hahn embedding theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_embedding_theorem), which offers a nice characterization of all totally ordered commutative groups.

Comment: What do you denote by $(G,.)$? the dot denotes the pair $(+,\le)$?

Comment: By the way if you don't assume $G$ commutative you'd need to clarify whether "ordered group" means the order is left-invariant or both left and right invariant. Both convention exist, so it's better write left-ordered group and bi-ordered group.

Comment: The proof of Theorem 6 is unnecessarily complicated. Let $a>1$. If $\{ a^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is not cofinal in $G$, it has a least upper bound $s$. Since $a^{-1}s<s$, we have $a^{-1}s\le a^n$ for some $n$. But then $s\le a^{n+1}<a^{n+2}\le s$, a contradiction.

Comment: @YCor Quite right. The results apply to biordered groups. I'm fairly sure they fail for left-ordered groups.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Oops, you're right, of course. I suspected that there might be a simpler argument than what I was able to come up with... ;-). I'm going to incorporate your argument in the post (giving credit to you, of course), and I'll also clean up the edit mess to make the post better readable for future visitors.

Comment: @YCor: I was indeed a bit lazy and surpressed the order relation in the notation. Admittedly, this is not particularly good style (even more so as I wrote down the group operation explicitly). Thanks also for your comment about bi-ordered groups. I thought that "ordered group" is usually used synonymously with "bi-ordered" group, but it seems that I was wrong.

Comment: Corollary 4 is very closely related to the classification of factors (von Neumann algebras with trivial center) into type I, type II, and type III.

Comment: @AndréHenriques: This sounds quite interesting (and quite surprising) to me. Could you elaborate a bit on it (or maybe give a reference where this relation is discussed)?

Comment: Let $R$ be a factor. Then the collection of all isomorphism classes of $R$-modules under the operation of direct sum is isomorphic to either $(\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\},+)$ (the factor is of type I), or $(\mathbb R_{\ge 0}\cup\{\infty\},+)$ (the factor is of type II), or $(\{0\}\cup\{\infty\},+)$ (the factor is of type III). Note that I'm over-simplifying things a tiny bit by not distinguishing between different sizes (cardinalities) of $\infty$.